# Ordering queryset based on related M2M fields

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to return a queryset based off of three models.

Location model

```
class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lng = models.FloatField()
```

User model (extended from Django User)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    user = OneToOneField(User)
    locations = ManyToManyField(Location)
```

Case Model

```
class Case(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    completed = models.BooleanField()
```

I'm using `geopy` to return locations close to an inputted lat/long

```
def get_locations_nearby_coords(latitude, longitude, max_distance=None):
    """
    Return objects sorted by distance to specified coordinates
    which distance is less than max_distance given in kilometers
    """
    # Great circle distance formula
    gcd_formula = "6371 * acos(cos(radians(%s)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(long) - radians(%s)) + sin(radians(%s)) * sin(radians(lat)))"
    distance_raw_sql = RawSQL(
        gcd_formula,
        (latitude, longitude, latitude)
    )
    qs = Location.objects.all().annotate(
        distance=distance_raw_sql).order_by('distance')
    if max_distance is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(distance__lt=max_distance)
    return qs
```

What I'm aiming to return, is the 10 closest `locations` ordered by the number of completed cases for each `UserProfile`

A user can have many locations, and a location can be associated with many users hence why I went with an m2m field.

I can't have any duplicates, however, a location can show twice in the list IF there are multiple users at that location, but the final list should be sliced at 10.

**EDIT:**

Trying to clarify what should be returned.

Let's say I have 3 locations that are close to me (this is already known data)

```
1. Location 1 (Closest)
2. Location 2 
3. Location 3 (Furthest)
```

`Location 1` Has 1 user, who's completed 3 cases. `Location 2` has two users, user 1 has completed 10 cases, and user 2 has completed 2. `Location 3` has 1 user with 4 completed cases. What should be returned is as follows

```
1. Location 2 - User 1 - 10 Cases
2. Location 3 - User 1 - 4 Cases
3. Location 1 - User 1 - 3 Cases
4. Location 2 - User 2 - 2 Cases
```

Comment: How are Cases linked to UserProfile or Location?

Comment: I noticed just before you commented that I'd missed out the relationship. I've edited the original question.

Comment: can you be more specific? "ordered by the number of completed cases for each `UserProfile`" I don't understand the "for each": one location can have many user profiles, each of which can have many closed cases. Do you want to annotate each of the 10 locations with the total number of closed cases (i.e. sum of all closed cases for all user profiles)? Or are you trying to get for each location the user profiles with the most closed cases? i.e. you want for each location an ordered list of users?

Comment: @dirkgroten I want 10 locations that are the closest to the user. For example, if there are 3 users that are at location A, that should count for 3 of the return locations, ordered by the total number of completed cases that user has DESC

Comment: I don't understand the part about 10 locations vs 3 users. Are you doing this for a specific user? Are you searching for users close by or locations? Sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: The important infomation here is the Location, and then the related UserProfile, completed cases is used for ordering only. Specifically because a location may have 2 users it should show the same location twice, once for each userprofile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd suggest to apply explicit relation names to use them in queries.

To append completed case count to your queryset you can use this:

```
qs = qs.annotate(completed_cases=Count('user__case', filter=Q(user__case__completed=True))
```

and the final slicing is as trivial as `[:10]`

```
qs = qs.order_by('distance', '-completed_cases`, 'id', )[:10]
```

id - to avoid randomness for the same distance and case count.

## UPD

```
# finding locations
...
qs = qs.order_by('distance', 'id', )[:10]

# finding users with completed cases
final_qs = User.objects.filter(locations__in=qs, ).\
    annotate(
        completed_cases=Count('case', filter=Q(case__completed=True),
        location_id=F('locations__id'),
    ).order_by('-completed_cases', 'id')[:10]
```

Comment: This seems to just return the user, opposed to the location with the user and case count annotated?

Comment: Isn't it what you described as desired output? Location, User, Case count.

Comment: It leaves me with User, case count and location id. The primary data that needs returning is Location

Comment: I can not access the location data without hitting the database again, as the only thing that's in this queryset relating to the location is a location_id

Comment: You can similarly add other fields, you have `qs` with the locations. To have full objects I surmise you'd need to `prefetch` them which is a separate query as well.

Comment: This seems to ignore the distance for `final_qs` it's important that distance still has an impact because if two or more userprofiles have completed the same amount of cases at two different locations the one with the lowest distance should come first.